# When passing 2 variables in jQuery selector there's no result but when typing the same string output it does

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

for example:

> var a = "1234";
>
> var b = "line1\\\\.5";

now this line of code:

> "#" + a + b;

puts out this string

> "#1234line1\\.5"

and when I enter it in the selector like this:

> $("#1234line1\\.5")

it shows the correct element

> but $("#" + a + b)

Does not

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Short answer: If the element exists as of when the code runs, your `$("#" + a + b)` code should find it.

Comment: `"#"+a+b"=="#1234line1\\\\.5"`, `"#1234line1\\.5"!="#1234line1\\\\.5"`

Comment: When asking this sort of question, ***always*** include the relevant HTML (in this case, we have to guess at what the `id` of the element you're trying to match is, reasonable guesses would be `1234line1.5` and `1234line1\.5`, but we shouldn't have to guess...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised it works in the console, the `id` selector is invalid. CSS [`id` selectors cannot start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).  You can escape it, though:

```
var a = "\\31 234"; // \\31 = 1, then you need the space to terminate the escape

var b = "line1\\.5";        // Removed a pair of \\ from this, I assume you
                            // don't have a backslash in the id

$("#" + a + b).html("Found it");
```

This works, for instance: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/fuciz/2/)

```
<div id="1234line1.5"></div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    var a = "\\31 234";

    var b = "line1\\.5";

    $("#" + a + b).html("Found it");
  })();
</script>
```

If you really have a backslash in the `id`, the escape for a backslash is `\5c`, which you write in a string literal as `\\5c`, so: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/fuciz/3/)

```
<div id="1234line1\.5"></div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    var a = "\\31 234";

    var b = "line1\\5c \\.5";

    $("#" + a + b).html("Found it");
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! my problem really was the 4 backslashes instead of 2. but the thing you said with the numbers in id's isn't relevant anymore in html5..

Comment: @Nemmy: Glad that helped. *"...but the thing you said with the numbers in id's isn't relevant anymore in html5..."* Yes, it is, CSS selector semantics aren't affected by the HTML spec; see the link. With jQuery, you'll *get away* with it if it's on its own (because jQuery will turn it into a call to `getElementById` which doesn't care about CSS), but if you combine anything with it, it will fail. Try it with `querySelector`, for instance, or in a stylesheet. The answer you've accepted is wrong (on that count).

Answer (score 0):

One thing first: Depending on the Doctype you use, IDs may not contain backslashes or start with numbers. Please check that first.

A backslash within a Javascript string indicates that the next character should be escaped. So if you want to use a backslash within your name, then you have to escape it with a leading backslash.

If you write a code like this:

```
$('#abc\\\\d')
```

then it refers to an element with the ID `abc\\d` (which may be illegal to use), because both of your backslashes are being escaped.

Comment: *"Depending on the Doctype you use, IDs may not contain backslashes..."* The doctype doesn't matter, HTML has never actually cared about the content of `id` attributes and browsers have always allowed just about anything (which is why the HTML5 spec changed the definition of what they could contain, to reflect reality on the ground; about half the spec is like that). Regardless of doctype, a CSS `id` selector cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not that the id starts with a digit, Html 5 supports this kind of ids

the problem is that you put 4 backslash instead of 2

so instead of searching for

```
#1234line1\.5
```

you searched for

```
#1234line1\\.5
```

just change it to

```
var b = "line1\\.5";
```

and it will work fine

Comment: *...Html 5 supports this kind of ids..."* Yes, it does; CSS does **not** (without escaping as I described in my answer). The selector `#1234` is invalid in CSS and *will* fail. The only reason it *seems( to work with jQuery is that jQuery will optimize a selector it thinks is just a simple id selector into a call to `getElementById`, which has never cared about CSS semantics (since it doesn't accept a selector). But combine that with anything (`#1234 div, `#1234.someClass`) or just use it with `querySelector` (or use it in a stylesheet) and you'll quickly find it fails.